# Swift - Getting Date from Month, Day, Year Components

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift4

How do you convert a DateComponents to a Date Object.
Currently, I have following code

```
Calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 15))
```

but I'm getting an error stating `"No 'date' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Date'`

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm still struggling with how to work with dates in Swift

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot call `date(from` on the type. You have to use an *instance* of the calendar, either the `current` calendar

```
Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 15))
```

or a fixed one

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create an instance of DateComponents to keep your code flexible
var dateComponents = DateComponents()

//create the date components
dateComponents.year = 2018
dateComponents.month = 1
dateComponents.day = 15
//dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
dateComponents.hour = 4
dateComponents.minute = 12

//make something useful out of it
func makeACalendarObject(){

//create an instance of a Calendar for point of reference ex: myCalendar, and use the dateComponents as the parameter
let targetCalendar = Calendar.current
let newCalendarObject = targetCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)


guard let newCalObject = newCalendarObject else {
    return
}
print(newCalObject)
}
//call the object
makeACalendarObject()
```